# How to get the value ot TextInput and add to Flatlist in React Native

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the value of TextInput and add to my flatList:
here is my TextInput

```
        <TextInput style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="   Money "
          placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          keyboardType='numeric'
          value = 'money'
        />
```

This is my Button that will add the value of TextInput into my Flatlist

```
 <Button
          title="Add me"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />

        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text style = {styles.item}> {item.name}</Text>)} />


    </View>
```

Comment: i am new here , so any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/humiliated-cereal)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ name: 'ketan' }]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 10, marginTop: 10 }}
        onChangeText={(name) => setName(name)}
        placeholder={'enter name'}
        value={name}
      />
      <Button
        title={'add me'}
        onPress={() => {
          if (name) setData([...data, { name: name }]);
          console.log('hi');
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: What if there i have `Picker` a  how can i insert it into flatlist?

Comment: Please write the code that you have tried and if you faced any issue with it or want to achieve certain behaviour that you are not able to implement then Post a question about it. I or someone else from the community will gladly help you :)

Answer (score 0):

just added

```
 <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text style = {styles.item}> {item.name}</Text>)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}  
           />
```

it worked